# Trying to web scrape Ebay but having trouble extracting the information to an EXCEL sheet

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-3.7

Attempting to extract some info off of an Ebay search page. When the script runs, it fails to export into a Json file. At least the EXCEL sheet is able to be created with the headings I am telling it to create. Any help would be appreciated. Upon further investigation, is the "iid" not something I can reference with BeautifulSoup?

> **div class="lvpic pic img left" iid="173992820900"**

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import datetime
 from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
 import urllib3
 import xlsxwriter

 urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
 url = 'https://www.ebay.com/e/fashion/sunglasses-under-10?rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3'
    total_added = 0

def make_soup(url):
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request("GET", url)
return BeautifulSoup(r.data,'lxml')

def main(url):
global total_added
db = TinyDB("db.json")

while url:
    print ("Web Page: ", url)
    soup = soup_process(url, db)
    nextlink = soup.find("link", rel="next")

    url = False
    if (nextlink):
        url = nextlink['href']

print ("Added ",total_added)

make_excel(db)

def soup_process(url, db):
global total_added

soup = make_soup(url)
results = soup.find_all("li", class_="lvresult")

for result in results:
    try:
       rec = {
            'ebaynum': result.div['iid'],
            # 'date': result.p.time['datetime'],
            'cost': gmoney(result.ul.li.span.string.strip()),
            'webpage': result.a['href'],
            'pic': gpic(result.a.img['img']),
            'descr': result.h3.a.string.strip(),
            # 'createdt': datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()
        }

   Result = Query()
       s1 = db.search(Result.ebaynum == rec["ebaynum"])

       if not s1:
            total_added += 1
            print ("Adding ... ", total_added)
            db.insert(rec)

    except (AttributeError, KeyError) as ex:
        pass

return soup

def gmoney(amt):
return float(amt.replace("$",""))

def gpic(ids):
idlist = ids.split(",")
first = idlist[0]
code = first.replace("1:","")
return "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/m/%s-l225.jpg" % code

def make_excel(db):
Headlines = ["EbayNum", "Cost", "Webpage", "Pic", "Desc"]
row = 0

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ebay.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column(0,0, 15) # pid
# worksheet.set_column(1,1, 20) # date
worksheet.set_column(2,2, 7)  # cost
worksheet.set_column(3,3, 10)  # webpage
worksheet.set_column(4,4, 7)  # picture
worksheet.set_column(5,5, 60)  # Description
# worksheet.set_column(6,6, 30)  # created date

for col, title in enumerate(Headlines):
    worksheet.write(row, col, title)

for item in db.all():
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, 0, item['ebaynum'] )
    # worksheet.write(row, 1, item['date'] )
    worksheet.write(row, 2, item['cost'] )
    worksheet.write_url(row, 3, item['webpage'], string='Web Page')
    worksheet.write_url(row, 4, item['pic'], string="Picture" )
    worksheet.write(row, 5, item['descr'] )
    # worksheet.write(row, 6, item['createdt'] )

workbook.close()

main(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not `link` you want but an `a` tag. Compare yours:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/e/fashion/sunglasses-under-10?rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
nextlink = soup.find("link", rel="next")

if nextlink:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

with

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/e/fashion/sunglasses-under-10?rt=nc&LH_ItemCondition=3')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
nextlink = soup.find("a", rel="next")

if nextlink:
    print("found")
else:
    print("not found")
```

---

I prefer a nice concise css attribute selector:

```
nextlink = soup.select_one('[rel=next]')
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) can be used to extract data in excel format:

```py
pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_excel(
    'ebay_listings.xlsx',    # name of the Excel file
    sheet_name='listings',   # name of the sheet name 
    index=False              # remove pandas row index (numeration) 
)
```

To extract all listings, you need to use pagination. Pagination is carried out by finding the CSS Selector of the "next page" button (in our case it is `.pagination__next`) and while the button is active on the page, the transition to the next page occurs using the `while` loop, when the button becomes inactive, the cycle exits.

How does button validation and pagination work:

```py
if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1             # go to next page  
    else:
        break
```

To get the required data, you need to get a "container", which is a CSS selector called [class selector](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#class_selector) that contains all the information about eBay search results i.e title, link, price and so on.

For ease of finding CSS Selectors, you can use the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension, which does not always work perfectly if the page is heavily using JS ( in this case we can).

Check code with pagination and extracting information to Excel in [`online IDE`](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-ebay-and-extracting-to-excel#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml
import pandas as pd

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}


params = {
    '_nkw': 'sunglasses under 10',           # search query  
    '_pgn': 1                                # page number
    #'LH_Sold': '1'                          # shows sold items
}

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    for products in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        title = products.select_one(".s-item__title span").text
        price = products.select_one(".s-item__price").text
        link = products.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]
        
        data.append({
          "title" : title,
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })

    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_excel(
    'ebay_listings.xlsx',    # name of the Excel file
    sheet_name='listings',   # name of the sheet name 
    index=False              # remove pandas row index (numeration) 
)
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code with pagination and extracting information to Excel:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os, json
import pandas as pd

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi api key    
    "engine": "ebay",                 # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",        # ebay domain
    "_nkw": "sunglasses under 10",    # search query
    "_pgn": 1                         # page number    
    #"LH_Sold": "1"                   # shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = organic_result.get("link")
        price = organic_result.get("price")

        data.append({
          "price" : price,
          "link" : link
        })
                    
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
        params['_pgn'] += 1

    else:
        break

#print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
pd.DataFrame(data=data).to_excel(
    'ebay_listings.xlsx',    # name of the Excel file
    sheet_name='listings',   # name of the sheet name 
    index=False              # remove pandas row index (numeration) 
)
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.